# Jung graph display on JFrame

Tags: java, graph, jung

I'm trying to reuse the code from Jung's web page (treecolapse.java; http://jung.sourceforge.net/applet/treecollapse.html), but I need that the graph's display occupies all the frame, not a part of it ...or at least that the display by default not be so little... how can I do that?

thanks! :D

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zy2XK.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hy5vA.png)

```
public class Visualizacion extends JApplet {

/**
 * the graph
 */
static org.graphstream.graph.Graph grafoDAA;
Forest<String,String> graph;Funciones f=new Funciones();
Factory<DirectedGraph<String,String>> graphFactory = new Factory<DirectedGraph<String,String>>() {

        public DirectedGraph<String, String> create() {
            return new DirectedSparseMultigraph<String,String>();
        }
    };
Factory<Tree<String,String>> treeFactory =new Factory<Tree<String,String>> () {

    public Tree<String, String> create() {
        return new DelegateTree<String,String>(graphFactory);
    }
};
Factory<String> edgeFactory = new Factory<String>() {
int i=0;
    public String create() {
        return "E"+i++;
    }};
Factory<String> vertexFactory = new Factory<String>() {
    int i=0;
    public String create() {
        return "V"+i++;
    }};
```

//  protected VertexStrokeHighlight vsh;
    /**
     * the visual component and renderer for the graph
     */
    VisualizationViewer vv;
    String root;
    TreeLayout layout;
    FRLayout layout1;
    TreeCollapser collapser;

```
public Visualizacion(org.graphstream.graph.Graph grafito) {
    grafoDAA=grafito;
    // create a simple graph for the demo
    graph = new DelegateForest<String,String>();

    createTree();

    layout = new TreeLayout<String,String>(graph);
    collapser = new TreeCollapser();

    Transformer<String,Paint>vertexPaint= new Transformer<String,Paint>(){
        public Paint transform(String i){
            Node node=grafoDAA.getNode(i);
            if(node.hasAttribute("ExcedeCaudal")){
                return Color.RED;}
            else{
                return Color.lightGray;}
        }
    };

    vv =  new VisualizationViewer<String,String>(layout, new Dimension(800,600));
    vv.addGraphMouseListener(new TestGraphMouseListener<String>());
    vv.setBackground(Color.white);
    vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeShapeTransformer(new EdgeShape.Line());
    vv.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelTransformer(new ToStringLabeller());
    vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeLabelTransformer(new ToStringLabeller());
    vv.getRenderContext().setVertexShapeTransformer(new ClusterVertexShapeFunction());
    vv.getRenderContext().setVertexFillPaintTransformer(vertexPaint);
    // add a listener for ToolTips
    vv.setVertexToolTipTransformer(new ToStringLabeller());
    vv.getRenderContext().setArrowFillPaintTransformer(new ConstantTransformer(Color.lightGray));




    Container content = getContentPane();
    final GraphZoomScrollPane panel = new GraphZoomScrollPane(vv);
    content.add(panel);

    final DefaultModalGraphMouse graphMouse = new DefaultModalGraphMouse();
    vv.setGraphMouse(graphMouse);

    //JComboBox modeBox = graphMouse.getModeComboBox();
    //modeBox.addItemListener(graphMouse.getModeListener());
   // graphMouse.setMode(ModalGraphMouse.Mode.PICKING);

    final ScalingControl scaler = new CrossoverScalingControl();

    //ver cual nodo se selecciona
    final PickedState<String> pickedState=vv.getPickedVertexState();
    pickedState.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
            Object subject=e.getItem();
            if(subject instanceof String){
                String vertice=(String)subject;
                if(pickedState.isPicked(vertice)){
                    System.out.println("Vertice "+vertice+" estÃ¡ seleccionado");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("Vertice "+vertice+"no estÃ¡ seleccionado");
                }
            }

        }
    });


    JButton plus = new JButton("+");
    plus.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            scaler.scale(vv, 1.1f, vv.getCenter());
        }
    });
    JButton minus = new JButton("-");
    minus.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            scaler.scale(vv, 1/1.1f, vv.getCenter());
        }
    });


    JButton collapse = new JButton("Collapse");
        collapse.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Collection picked =new HashSet(vv.getPickedVertexState().getPicked());
            if(picked.size() == 1) {
                Object root = picked.iterator().next();
                Forest inGraph = (Forest)layout.getGraph();

                try {
                    collapser.collapse(vv.getGraphLayout(), inGraph, root);
                } catch (InstantiationException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                vv.getPickedVertexState().clear();
                vv.repaint();
            }
        }});

    JButton expand = new JButton("Expand"); 
        expand.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Collection picked = vv.getPickedVertexState().getPicked();
            for(Object v : picked) {
                if(v instanceof Forest) {
                    Forest inGraph = (Forest)layout.getGraph();
                    collapser.expand(inGraph, (Forest)v);
                }
                vv.getPickedVertexState().clear();
               vv.repaint();
            }
        }});

    JPanel scaleGrid = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,0));
    scaleGrid.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Zoom"));

    JPanel controls = new JPanel();
    scaleGrid.add(plus);
    scaleGrid.add(minus);
    controls.add(scaleGrid);
    controls.add(collapse);
    controls.add(expand);
    content.add(controls, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}


private void createTree() {

for(Node node:grafoDAA){
     graph.addVertex(node.getId());
    // System.out.println("node id "+node.getId());
}

for (Edge edge: grafoDAA.getEachEdge()){
     String padre=edge.getNode0().getId();
     String hijo=edge.getNode1().getId();
     String caudal=(edge.getAttribute("Caudal"));
     graph.addEdge(caudal, padre,hijo);   
    }
```

}

```
 /**
 * a demo class that will create a vertex shape that is either a polygon or star.
 * The number of sides corresponds to the number
 * of vertices that were collapsed into the vertex represented by
 * this shape.
 * 
 * @author Tom Nelson
 *
 * @param <V>
 */
class ClusterVertexShapeFunction<V> extends EllipseVertexShapeTransformer<V> {

    ClusterVertexShapeFunction() {
        setSizeTransformer(new ClusterVertexSizeFunction<V>(20));
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Shape transform(V v) {
        if(v instanceof Graph) {
            int size = ((Graph)v).getVertexCount();
            if (size < 8) {   
                int sides = Math.max(size, 3);
                return factory.getRegularPolygon(v, sides);
            }
            else {
                return factory.getRegularStar(v, size);
            }
        }
        return super.transform(v);
    }
}

/**
 * A demo class that will make vertices larger if they represent
 * a collapsed collection of original vertices
 * @author Tom Nelson
 *
 * @param <V>
 */
class ClusterVertexSizeFunction<V> implements Transformer<V,Integer> {
    int size;
    public ClusterVertexSizeFunction(Integer size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public Integer transform(V v) {
        if(v instanceof Graph) {
            return 30;
        }
        return size;
    }
}

static class TestGraphMouseListener<V> implements GraphMouseListener<V> {

        public void graphClicked(V v, MouseEvent me) {
                if(me.getClickCount()==2){
                    System.err.println("Vertex "+v+" fui doble click");
                }
            System.err.println("Vertex "+v+" was clicked at ("+me.getX()+","+me.getY()+")");
        }
        public void graphPressed(V v, MouseEvent me) {
            System.err.println("Vertex "+v+" was pressed at ("+me.getX()+","+me.getY()+")");
        }
        public void graphReleased(V v, MouseEvent me) {
            System.err.println("Vertex "+v+" was released at ("+me.getX()+","+me.getY()+")");
        }
}



public void execute(){

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    Container content = frame.getContentPane();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    content.add(new Visualizacion(grafoDAA));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

}

}

Comment: have you tried something? It is hard to give answer without your code

Comment: Thanks! I'm new using Jung and any help is welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the TreeLayout with the default x and y spacing.  Try increasing the spacing:

http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/layout/TreeLayout.html#TreeLayout(edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Forest, int, int)